# invalid syntax error while installed tweepy in anaconda python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, tweepy

I am very new to python and anaconda. I am trying to install tweepy using pip install command

```
pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple tweepy
```

I had referring to this command in

```
https://anaconda.org/pypi/tweepy
```

I am getting the below error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-3-57dd52ca9b36>", line 1
    pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple tweepy
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Tried a lot searching for this, but could not find one which can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to run that in your command shell, not a Python REPL.